Best way for createdAt/updatedAt fields in SwiftData?
Coming from a PostgreSQL/Django background, I'm used to having automatic createdAt and updatedAt timestamps on my database tables. I'd like to implement similar functionality in SwiftData, but I'm not sure if this is the idiomatic approach or if there are better alternatives (like History protocol).
Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve:
@Model
class Note {
    var title: String
    var content: String
    var createdAt: Date
    var updatedAt: Date
    
    init(title: String, content: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.createdAt = Date()
        self.updatedAt = Date()
    }
}

I have a few specific questions:

Is this the correct approach for tracking creation/modification times in SwiftData, or is there a more idiomatic way?

If this is the right approach, how can I make updatedAt update automatically when any property changes? Currently, I would need to manually set it in every view:


struct EditNoteView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Bindable var note: Note
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $note.title)
            .onChange(of: note.title) {
                note.updatedAt = Date() // Need to do this manually
                try? modelContext.save()
            }
    }
}


How does this work with SwiftData's autosave functionality? If SwiftData automatically saves changes, how can I ensure updatedAt is always current without explicitly setting it?
Should I consider using the History protocol instead? If so, how would that implementation look?

I've searched the WWDC sessions and documentation but haven't found clear guidance on timestamp tracking patterns in SwiftData.
Any help or guidance on best practices would be appreciated! Preferably an approach that works both in iOS 17 and iOS 18.



You want updatedAt to contain the timestamp when the property is set, not when the changes are saved, right? If so, why is autosave relevant?

It's best to think of SwiftData like a persisted model and not a database. When you save it saves all changes to the context not just the one you think you are saving so best to leave it to autosave so it can be done efficiently at the right time.
